# uWSGI embedding python interpreter

Tags: python, uwsgi

I've read [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Embed.html) that you can embed python scripts, configurations and templates/directories in uWSGI.

Is it possible to also embed the python interpreter itself (like PyInstaller does) in a uWSGI binary? Maybe if you include the full virtualenv root directory? How would you specify which python binary to run scripts under?